# Detecting submit event is raised because of button click

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to find out whether onsubmit event was raised because onclick event was raised ?
E.g., when an `<input type="submit" />` is clicked, onclick event is raised and then onsubmit event. However, sometimes it happens the form isn't submitted i.e. onsubmit isn't raised.

Steps to reproduce (the form is ajax form and it refreshes itself, tested on IE10) :
1) a form is submitted by clicking the button,
2) the ajax request finished and updated the form,
3) 5 milliseconds later, the button is clicked again (same way as in step 1) but this time onclick is fired but onsubmit is not. If I click the button, e.g., 500 ms after the form refresh, everything's fine

I use
`$("form input[type=submit], form input[type=image]").live("click", function (e) {     console.log("click"); }`
`$("form").live("submit", function (e) { console.log("submit"); }`
to see that onsubmit wasn't raised

Thank you

Comment: post some codes you've tried so far

Comment: _"sometimes it happens the form isn't submitted"_ - Do you mean this happens seemingly randomly and you can't figure out why? Please show your code.

Comment: the more relevant code you post the more relevant answers you'll get .people cant guess what your problem is.

Comment: Please show us your setup and your javascript. A click on a submit button will submit the form (without validation errors at least).

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't return false and the form is actually submitted therefor triggering a page load. You should not use .live as well. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but I can't reproduce in Firefox, also you should not use .live:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").delegate(null,"submit", function(){
        console.log("submitting");
        return false;
    });
    $("#submit").click();
    $("#submit").click();
    $("#submit").click();
    $("#submit").click();
});


<form id="form">
    <input type="submit" id="submit"></input>
</form>
```